# Magento 2: Forgot Password mail not receiving to some customers

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account, password-recovery

I am facing a weird issue, some of the customers not receiving password resetting email(*not in spam also*) after they request Forgot password, but I have tested with several test accounts these are working fine, not sure what's happening with other customer, anyone familiar with this issue? any logs for this? can I check through the database?

Comment: have you asked them to look under spam ? or some firewall blocking your domain

Comment: Yes, they sure not in spam!!!

Comment: For the hotmail we are facing issue. Check with ur email provider. It's blocking mail from ur domain.

Comment: Oh, I see, but these are ...@gmail not sure which email client they using